# drupal commerce rule to skip duplicate sku in cart

Tags: commerce, rules

I have a site and i am using drupal commerce module. i want to set a rule which will prevent the user to add a product twice in the cart. suppose a user add a product A and after that if he add the same product in the same cart than the system should generate a message that the same product is already added in your cart you can add another product.

I tried to create a rule but it works on the total quantity of cart not on total quantity of same product in the cart. please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unique field](https://drupal.org/project/unique_field) , [autosku](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_autosku) and tokens module

using that module set the name of sku using tokens
While generating sku use tokens

the parameters which u know differentiates 2 products should be used in tokens

Like if quantity and size is the parameter which differentiates your 2 products and defines two products as unique
then 
using tokens(for e.g.) [product:qty] and [product:size]
set the sku title
and using unique field set the sku as required and unique field

You can try the following function to edit the quantity :
you can set cart quantity for a single item to be default value 1.
hook_commerce_cart_line_item_refresh($line_item, $order_wrapper)

> Allows modules to perform additional processing to refresh an
>   individual line item on a shopping cart order.
>
> Prior to this hook being invoked, product line items will have already
>   had their sell prices refreshed via the creation of a new line item
>   for the same product being passed through Rules for calculation.
>
> Parameters
>
> $line_item: A line item object that should be updated as necessary for
>   the refresh.
>
> $order_wrapper: An EntityMetadataWrapper for the order the line item
>   is attached to.

Comment: HI Harshal.  thanks for your reply. but i did not actually get the point. i want user add a product to cart . when again he/she click on add to cart button for same product then it should not be added in cart and print message that same product is already there in your cart

Comment: sorry I thought  u wanted autosku ,as per your needs you can set cart quantity for a single item to be  default value 1

Comment: pls check the function it might help